# Can't get z-index to bring content outside overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project with an old website that I'm trying not to change too much in the way of structure (not in the budget). I'm on the very last piece of css and having an issue. Without getting into design details much, I have an element that is styled to look like a ribbon and hangs on the outside of the main content section. The `overflow` on the `#inner` container is cutting it off, but `overflow` is needed to contain all the posts.

I've [put together a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/emW2q/) that replicates the issue, please ignore the horrible non-styling of this example, simply trying to show the issue.

If you hide the `overflow: hidden;` within `#inner`, you will see how the `.category` hangs around the outside. I keep trying to use `z-index` and `position: relative;` to resolve the issue but it's not working.

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent container has an overflow of hidden it does not matter what position or z-index it's children has, it will always cut it off.

Try adding your ribbon with div class "outer". Let this outer wrap the inner and give it a position of relative.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>        
    <div class="inner">
        Article thingy
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you can keep your overflow hidden and still add things around your article. Plus z-index of 1 would have the same effect as z-index: 999

Comment: I figured that overflow on the parent was an absolute. The issue is that the ribbon or `.category` must be contained within the `.post` as it's positioning is absolute to the upper right corner of `.post`, it can't be positioned above the `#inner` in the DOM because that's a wrapper for the entire content section. Might have to change the design, but maybe someone has a trick yet.